# find Faces Camera android

Tags: android, camera, augmented-reality, android-2.2-froyo

I'm working on and Augmented reality app for android 2.2 but i want in integrate a face recognition module... i try to use the findFaces method from FaceDetector class but it recive a bitmap... and i want to send a camera preview any idea?

Comment: It's tagged as Android, so it's probably Java

Comment: Found some solutions here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4125821/face-detection-in-android