# face matching open source for IOS/Android

Tags: android, ios, open-source, face-recognition

I want to make an iOS/Android app that does like this: take an photo of user's face, then search in Data Base to find most similar face by comparing face's features, skin color tone .etc.

I want to do this compare by feature matching . It does this by comparing structure, shape and proportions of the face; distance between the eyes, nose, mouth and jaw; upper outlines of the eye sockets; the sides of the mouth; location of the nose and eyes; and the area surrounding the check bones. How can I do this ?

Is there any open source solution for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to checkout

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/

OpenCV has elements to build this up and works on Android and iOS.  Other options:

[Face Detection in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4125821/face-detection-in-android)