# Face detection on Android

Tags: android, detection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Face Detection in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4125821/face-detection-in-android)

I want to start a course work project for Android OS using the Face Detector API. It should detect where the face on the picture is. And just mark it by surrounding it with a rectangle. Just like this app does: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vediket.facerecog&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS52ZWRpa2V0LmZhY2VyZWNvZyJd

Can someone provide me sample code please?