# Put an outline of a person while using camera

Tags: android, android-camera

I don´t know if this is possible. I want to add an outline of a person in the moment that the user is using the camera to be easier for the people to take the right photo for the porpoise of the application (put different faces in order of the real face). Someone know how can I make it?

Comment: You'd need to study up on digital signal processing to be able to figure out where a person is in the picture.  A good first guess would be to look for skin tones next to areas of high contrast.  But this kind of thing isn't built into Android, you're going to have to write it yourself and its non-trivial.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4125821/face-detection-in-android has everything you need to know.

Comment: What I need is to put the outline not to know where is the person. If there is an outline while you are using the camera the user know where to take the photo. I don´t need to detect the person or the face... just to put an outline in the moment of taking the photo. Is that possible?