# face detection not detecting faces, Android

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas, crop, face-detection

I am using Android native facedetection for my app where the bitmap is given as input and the faces should get detected. It works good for bitmap with large faces. but not working for bitmap with small faces.

I tried on a picture bitmap which contains 10 faces , but only 3 are detected.

```
detectedFaces=new FaceDetector.Face[NUMBER_OF_FACES];
    faceDetector=new FaceDetector(resultBmp.getWidth(),resultBmp.getHeight(),NUMBER_OF_FACES);
    NUMBER_OF_FACE_DETECTED=faceDetector.findFaces(resultBmp, detectedFaces);

for(int count=0;count<NUMBER_OF_FACE_DETECTED;count++)
    {

if(count==0){

 face1=detectedFaces[count];
            midPoint1=new PointF();
            face1.getMidPoint(midPoint1);

            eyeDistance=face1.eyesDistance();

        left1 = midPoint1.x - (float)(1.8 * eyeDistance);
        right1 = midPoint1.x + (float)(1.4 * eyeDistance);
          top1 = midPoint1.y - (float)(1.4 * eyeDistance);
           bottom1 = midPoint1.y + (float)(1.8 * eyeDistance);

Bitmap bmface = Bitmap.createBitmap(resultBmp, (int) left1+5, (int) top1+5, (int) (2.8 * eyeDistance)+5, (int) (3.6 * eyeDistance)+5);

}
if(count==1)
{
----
}
-------------and so-on till count==10---------

  }
```

Now please suggest me something. facedetection should work on small faces too. the picture i used is[image]

thanks in advance

Comment: for a full example see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4125821/face-detection-in-android

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I figured it out. For those having this issue. Face detection only works on bitmap after it is
converted to RGB_565 using this

```
BitmapFactory.Options bitmapFatoryOptions=new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bitmapFatoryOptions.inPreferredConfig=Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
 mybitmapss=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.familyportrait2,bitmapFatoryOptions);
```

Comment: Thanks! I'd seen the documentation for `findFaces` mention the need for 565 format, but I'd ignored it since it wasn't erroring.