# Face reconization in android

Tags: java, android, face-recognition

I want to compare the 2 images(images of people)and want a result that these are of same person or not(By Face recognization).I have to do this for millions of images so I cannot do it manually .Is there any api for android that can be used in my app.

Comment: I think there is no built-in function. But maybe you could use OpenCV. It provides APIs for simple pattern matching http://docs.opencv.org/master/de/da9/tutorial_template_matching.html or even a more complex object detection. http://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/d64/tutorial_table_of_content_objdetect.html

Comment: Also, you might want to check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4125821/face-detection-in-android?rq=1)

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Camera.Face](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Face.html) or [FaceDetector.Face](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/media/FaceDetector.Face.html) class. Take parameters of face on both photos and compare their parameters using e.g. `eyesDistance()`. If those parameters quite the same -> its the same person.